# Implementing a countdown to open a website

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, timer

I am currently working on a website that needs to open up when a timer counting down to a specific date runs out.  JavaScript with a redirect is out of the question since JS tends to be client-side, which would allow users to simply change their computers' clocks to the appropriate date to unlock the website.

I'm thinking I should use the server's internal date and time in some way, but I need the timer to update in real-time and the website to unlock only on that date.  Making this as dynamic as possible, using PHP (and if I have to, AJAX), would be the preferred strategy.

How would you guys recommend I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
$openingtime = 1310402546; 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] < $openingtime){
   echo "not open yet";
   exit;
}
```

just use http://www.epochconverter.com/ or something to convert to timestamp..

---

**EDIT:**

Get required files from http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

in main page or something, that is included everywhere (**but** countdown.php or you'll make endless loop) put this:

```
$openingtime = 1310402546; 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] < $openingtime){
   header("location:countdown.php");
   exit;
}
```

countdown.php
head:

```
  <style type="text/css">@import "jquery.countdown.css";</style> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
```

body:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeleft=<?php echo ($openingtime - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"]); ?>;
 $('#countdown').countdown({until: +timeleft});</script>
```

unless i made a mistake with copy paste it works

Comment: I was more or less referring to a way I could integrate a live countdown script (something like a Flash clock counting down, or a JavaScript clock).  This could easily be in the header of the page generator script that'll be going in the site's PHP core.  Perhaps I could `header("Location: countdown.php");` in place of `echo "not open yet";` if I were to use this.

Comment: so how about using jquery? http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html and check the **Relative** tab, since all other can annoy you with _timezone_. And you just use `$openingtime - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"]` to get time left. So this would go in countdown.php

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript with a redirect is out of the question since JS tends to be client-side, which would allow users to simply change their computers' clocks to the appropriate date to unlock the website.

You could still use JavaScript, and display an server-side error on the site if it is accessed before the unlock date.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a php GET method that gets the [server's time](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp). Then with AJAX do a GET request to the php method every minute or so using [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Once the time/date matches the time/date you want, then open it up with javascript.

There are quite a few Javascript clock scripts out there:

http://www.ricocheting.com/code/javascript/html-generator/digital-clock

http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/digitalclock.html

[Google it](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=js%20digital%20clock%20script)